# show the digits between underscore and dot

Tags: oracle11g

in oracle

I want to show the digits between underscore and dot

For example : pSE1001335806_**17950**.dat 
So column will be = 17950

But for : pSE1001311462_**4558**.dat
The column will be = 4558

How can I do that????

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression for this; if you can generalise it so the second block of alphanumeric characters, then something this simple would work:

```
regexp_substr(<value>, '([[:alnum:]]+)', 1, 2)
```

With a CTE to generate your sample values:

```
with files as
(
    select 'pSE1001335806_17950.dat' as filename from dual
    union all select 'pSE1001311462_4558.dat' from dual
)
select regexp_substr(filename, '([[:alnum:]]+)', 1, 2)
from files;

REGEXP_SUBSTR(FILENAME,'([[:ALNUM:]]+)',1,2)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
17950
4558
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
select regexp_replace('pSE1001335806_17950.dat','.*_([0-9]+).dat','\1') from dual
```